# Dotnet MAUI with MVMM - Dynamic dataTemplate based on ObservableCollection<T> where T is an interface

Tags: c#, xaml, datatemplate, maui, .net-maui

I'm trying de build a new DotNet MAUI application.

I have a datasource of this kind :
`public ObservableCollection<IIpxElement> IpxElements { get; }`

With this in the Xaml

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding IpxElements}" SelectionMode="None">
   <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
     <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2" />
  </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
</CollectionView>
```

I don't want to create a DataTemplateSelector for each type who implements `IIpxElement`

When i was using WPF and Caliburn Micro i could do something like that :

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="IpxElements">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The binding between the Name and the ItemSource was automatic but here i don't really care.

I just want to have a "dynamic" dataTemplate based on associated concrete type (of ViewModel) and view (by naming convention) since i could have a lot of implementation.

Is there anyway of doing something like this ?

Thanks you,

Cyril

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by a dynamic dataTemplate. Can you add code to show how you would do it if you had just two implementors? That is easy to do, using a single DataTemplateSelector referring to two DataTemplates and two ViewModels that implement IIpxElement. I understand you don't want to do this for a lot of implementors, but then it becomes clear exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieve what i want using a DataTemplateSelector and using reflection

```
public class CustomDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
     {
         var viewModelConcreteType = item.GetType();
         var viewFullName = viewModelConcreteType.FullName.Replace("ViewModel", "View");
         var viewType = Type.GetType(viewFullName);
         var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(viewType);
         dataTemplate.SetValue(BindableObject.BindingContextProperty, item);
         return dataTemplate;
     }
}
```

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
   <resources:CustomDataTemplateSelector x:Key="customDataTemplateSelector" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding IpxElements}" 
                SelectionMode="None" 
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource customDataTemplateSelector}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
</CollectionView>
```

Since i'm using naming convention it was the easiest way to do it.

The View used is the DataTemplate have to be a ContentView and not ContentPage.

Comment: Your OnSelectTemplate returns a new DataTemplate for every call.
Per microsoft's guidelines you should not be doing that as it can cause a memory leak.
  

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/datatemplate?view=net-maui-7.0
  

"The DataTemplateSelector subclass must not return new instances of a DataTemplate on each call. Instead, the same instance must be returned. Failure to do so will create a memory leak and will disable control virtualization."

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the specific situation, we generally use two methods to achieve it.

If the gap in the layout of the items is large, we recommend using [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector).

If the layout of the items does not vary much, you can try to add some fields(e.g. `bool isVisible`) to display  or hide some controls based on the associated concrete type (of ViewModel) and view (by naming convention) you mentioned above.

Of course, you can also use it in conjunction with the above methods.

Comment: How can you use a DataTemplateSelector when you have 100 implementations ?
You have to specify each type ?
When you have multiple assemblies you can't declare the type because you don't know it. It's why we use DI no ?!

Comment: If the layout of the items does not vary much, you can try the second way.